# Confirm Sale and skip Payment - net_amount is getting added to prev_outstanding_balance

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm using (Bahmni with) Odoo-10 and when I press Confirm button in the Sale Order and skip/cancel the Register Payment step, the **Total Outstanding** amount is displayed as double the actual amount.

Here, the **Previous Balance** field is taking the amount in the current sale order, and then this value is also getting added with the **Net Amount**.

---

When I check the *bahmni-erp/bahmni-addons/bahmni_sale/models/sale_order.py*, I observe this code under SaleOrder class

```
prev_outstanding_balance = fields.Monetary(string="Previous Outstanding Balance",
                                               compute=_calculate_balance)
total_outstanding_balance = fields.Monetary(string="Total Outstanding Balance",
                                                compute=_amount_all)

def _calculate_balance(self):
    for order in self:
        order.prev_outstanding_balance = 0.0
        order.total_outstanding_balance = 0.0
        total_receivable = order._total_receivable()
        order.prev_outstanding_balance = total_receivable

def _amount_all(self):
        """
        Compute the total amounts of the SO.
        """
        for order in self:
            ...
            order.update({
                'amount_untaxed': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.round(amount_untaxed),
                'amount_tax': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.round(amount_tax),
                'amount_total': amount_total + round_off_amount,
                'round_off_amount': round_off_amount,
                'total_outstanding_balance': order.prev_outstanding_balance + amount_total + round_off_amount
            })

def _total_receivable(self):
    receivable = 0.0
    if self.partner_id:
        self._cr.execute("""SELECT l.partner_id, at.type, SUM(l.debit-l.credit)
                      FROM account_move_line l
                      LEFT JOIN account_account a ON (l.account_id=a.id)
                      LEFT JOIN account_account_type at ON (a.user_type_id=at.id)
                      WHERE at.type IN ('receivable','payable')
                      AND l.partner_id = %s
                      AND l.full_reconcile_id IS NULL
                      GROUP BY l.partner_id, at.type
                      """, (self.partner_id.id,))
        for pid, type, val in self._cr.fetchall():
            if val is None:
                val=0
            receivable = (type == 'receivable') and val or -val
    return receivable
```

Why it's adding the Net Amount in the current Sale Order to the prev_outstanding_balance?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Eg:-  Untaxed Amount: 1,875, 
Net Amount : 1,875,  
Previous Balance:  1,875
Total Outstanding:  3,750